# The format of model when using tf.save in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

As we know, we can save the model using `tf.save()` when training.

But what is the format of the stored model file? Is it possible to read the file using `fread` or something?

Comment: The format is specified as [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), a format with various usages from Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details about the format of the file and how to parse from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/tool_developers/index.html.

See a quick example:

```
graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
with open(FLAGS.graph, "rb") as f:
  if FLAGS.input_binary:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read)
  else:
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def)
```

You can find more examples in the web page.